QuickOSM-Quick query vectors input issue
I tried to import a range of vectors into QGIS using QuickOSM, but it always automatically selects only one type of vector. For example, when I input "shop" to include all kinds of shops, it only selects "shop-supermarkets." How can I solve this issue?
